# Insert date difference field in MS-Word

Tags: automation, ms-word, ms-office, field

I need to insert in CV created in MS Word document the age of the people.

I know the birth date of the person.

Is there a way to insert a field that will automatically calculates the age?

- Johny Walker, `{FIELD=NOW-BIRTHDATE}` years.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a 100%, but it may do:

[image: word date]

```
{={ DATE \@ "YY" } - { MERGEFIELD DOB \@ "YY" } + 
    {IF { DATE \@ "MM" } - { MERGEFIELD DOB \@ "MM" } 1 0 }}
```

Use ctrl+F9 to add the {}, F9 to recalculate and alt+F9 to display the result.